# Are Android hardware backed credential storage wiped upon factory reset?

Tags: android, keychain, trustzone

I'm interested in storing data in hardware backed storage(in TrustZone) as described in https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html.

Do these survive a factory reset?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys stored in android keystore are invalidated when the device security settings (device-lock) are changed by the user. Presumably a hardware reset, that also reset the security setting will invalidate the keys

In this article [Android security the forgetful keystore][1] is analyzed the behaviour of Android Keystore and hardware support

[1] :http://doridori.github.io/android-security-the-forgetful-keystore/

Comment: Thanks. Wow, that's messy, different behavior on different KeyStore configuration and different OS versions.